# Wo kann man im Internet die deutsche Sprache üben?

Tags: pronunciation, learning

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[Are there websites where one can practice German conversation whether through typing or through audio?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33120)*

Ich suche etwas wie Skype, Google Talk, Hangouts, …, wo es Gruppen gibt, in denen man die deutsche Sprache bzw. Aussprache üben kann. Hat jemand eine Idee? Am besten ein PG, das auch für Minderjährige tauglich ist.

Comment: Was ist ein PG?

Comment: @CarstenS „PG“ und „Minderjährige“ in einem Satz lässt mich an Filmfreigaben denken. Gemäß der [BBFC](http://www.bbfc.co.uk/what-classification/pg), [Wikipedia/BBFC](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Board_of_Film_Classification#Freigaben), [Wikipedia/MPAA](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America#Bewertungskategorien) und der [SPIO](https://www.spio-fsk.de/?seitid=553&tid=469) entspricht das ungefähr der hiesigen FSK-6 (mit Elternbegleitung) bzw. FSK-12 (ohne Elternbegleitung). Falls das hier mit „PG“ überhaupt gemeint ist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eine Möglichkeit wäre [Tandem](https://www.tandem.net/). Ich nutze den Dienst selbst bisher nicht, habe ihn mir aber vor einiger Zeit für später vorgemerkt. Soweit ich das Prinzip verstanden habe, können sich auf der Plattform sozusagen "Paare" finden: Wenn Deine Muttersprache zum Beispiel Englisch ist und Du Deutsch lernst, kannst Du dort jemanden suchen, dessen Muttersprache Deutsch ist und der Englisch lernt. Den kannst Du dann zum Sprachüben einladen.

Answer (score 0):

http://deutsch.info/de/courses/a1

In der Ecke links unten kannst du die Sprache von Deutsch auf Englisch umstellen.

Du kannst auch googeln: deutsch lernen, freie online kurse.
Da findest du jede Menge Möglichkeiten.

Comment: warum stellst nicht Du die Sprache um???

Comment: Gerne. Ich wußte ja nicht, ob du die Seiten lieber auf Deutsch oder auf Englisch hast. http://deutsch.info/en