# Are there websites where one can practice German conversation whether through typing or through audio?

Tags: learning

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Wo kann man im Internet die deutsche Sprache üben?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15637)*

Im learning German on my own, so Im trying to find websites where I can make conversations in order to improve my speaking skills. Are there any?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wo kann man im Internet die deutsche Sprache üben?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15637/wo-kann-man-im-internet-die-deutsche-sprache-%c3%bcben)

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck [If the language is different, the questions are not dupes](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/807).

Answer (score 3):

I like https://en.duolingo.com/
I practiced spanish with these website/app and it is fun as well as very helpful. Maybe that is something for you?

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Speaky](https://www.speaky.com/) and found very helpful language speakers there. It is a social learning app where you can find a language partner to start a text or video chat in order to learn his/her language.
 Good luck with your German learning.

[EDIT] In the last few months I have been using an app called [HelloTalk](https://www.hellotalk.com/#en) and its pretty helpful. I am able to find a lot of helpful users :) So check that out too.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest the best way to learn, is in conversation.
I searched for sides but they where all extremely basic and some of them had mistakes (smaller ones but still) on the first side, learning there will make you sound like a small child.
I learned my English mostly in comment sections. Here you have to write small texts that stand in context to a previous statements, while avoiding to sit too long at one text. Also you switch through many topics and you learn to research missing words and grammatical rules.

If you can safely write comments without irritating readers too much and without looking for too many things, you should continue with professional language courses. (This is also what I am currently doing for my English skills and compared to what I learned in 10 years of English lessons in school I got quite far.)

Answer (score 0):

Verbling has a community section where groups form to practice German.  The best part is that the group will indicate the target level, and you can create one yourself.  The groups are free, but you do have to sign up.  It uses Google Groups/Hangouts for the conversations.  You can practice both spoken and written German here, although the emphasis would be on spoken German.

https://www.verbling.com/community

Answer (score -1):

We are a very small group of pensioners who enjoy the german language and have our own forum where we like to practice. Our forum is free to join and we would really like to hear from you.

Unser Kreis wird immer kleiner und wir brauchen dringend neue Mitglieder.

You can find us in the internet at: boltonanglogermancircle

Comment: Und jetzt clicke ich "skip"...